# Rolling compare using Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:
df1:

```
        Min Max
2022-01-01  97  98
2022-01-02  96  97
2022-01-03  95  95
2022-01-04  94  96
2022-01-05  93  95
2022-01-06  94  96
2022-01-07  94  96
2022-01-08  95  98
```

And df2:

```
    value
2022-01-01  92
2022-01-02  92
2022-01-03  92
2022-01-04  99
2022-01-05  96
2022-01-06  92
2022-01-07  92
2022-01-08  92
```

For each value in the df2 i would like to evaluate if this value is between max and min in the previous three rows in df1:

- The first three rows will be NaN:
- 2022-01-04: 99 is not within Min and Max for the three previous values -> False
- 2022-01-05: 96 is within Min and Max for both 2022-01-02 and 2022-01-04 -> True
- And so on

Is it possible to do this in a fast way using Pandas, the Dataframes are large? I want to avoid to iterate.

Comment: Can you post 2 examples of your dfs so that we can try out?

Comment: Do you want the `value` in between `Min` and `Max` of some previous row of `df1`? Or just between the `min` of the `Min` and `max` of the `Max`?

Comment: The first, between min and max for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient approach would be to use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 3
# pad the array to prepend N-1 values
# this enables to compute partial rollings
# like pandas's "min_periods"
a = np.pad(df1[['min', 'max']].astype(float),
           ((N-1,0), (0,0)), mode='constant',
           constant_values=np.nan)

# form the rolling windows
a = swv(a, N, axis=0)

b = df2[['value']].to_numpy()

# compare each row to all items in the window
# with both min and max values
# aggregate to True if any is True
df2['flag'] = ((a[:, 0] <= b) & (a[:, 1] >= b)).any(1)

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
            value   flag
2022-01-01     92  False
2022-01-02     92  False
2022-01-03     92  False
2022-01-04     99  False
2022-01-05     96   True
2022-01-06     92  False
2022-01-07     92  False
2022-01-08     92  False
```

Intermediate `a`:

```
array([[[nan, nan, 97.],
        [nan, nan, 98.]],

       [[nan, 97., 96.],
        [nan, 98., 97.]],

       [[97., 96., 95.],
        [98., 97., 95.]],

       [[96., 95., 94.],
        [97., 95., 96.]],

       [[95., 94., 93.],
        [95., 96., 95.]],

       [[94., 93., 94.],
        [96., 95., 96.]],

       [[93., 94., 94.],
        [95., 96., 96.]],

       [[94., 94., 95.],
        [96., 96., 98.]]])
```

Comment: Looks promising, I will test and try to understand what is happening...

Comment: @Jonas I added some comments for clarity, don't hesitate to ask if you have questions ;)

Comment: Thanks! Works really good and I think I understand what it is doing...at least most of it!